# .net MVC Streaming MP4 to iDevice issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, ios, asp.net-mvc, html

Ive got a bit of a issue with a piece of code I've been working on to serve video. The code is below:

```
public ResumingFileStreamResult GetMP4Video(string videoID)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string clipLocation = string.Format("{0}\\Completed\\{1}.mp4", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VideoLocation"].ToString(), videoID);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(clipLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            ResumingFileStreamResult fsr = new ResumingFileStreamResult(fs, "video/mp4");

            return fsr;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<video controls preload poster="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Videos/{0}_2.jpg", Model.VideoID))">
    <source src="@Url.Action("GetMP4Video", "Video", new { videoID = Model.VideoID })" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="@Url.Action("GetWebMVideo", "Video", new { videoID = Model.VideoID })" type="video/webm" />

        <object id="flowplayer" data="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf")" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360">
            <param name="movie" value="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf")" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="config={'playlist':['@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Videos/{0}_2.jpg", Model.VideoID))',{'url':'@Url.Action("GetMP4Video", "Video", new { videoID = Model.VideoID })','autoPlay':false}]}" />
        </object>
</video>
```

My problem is this setup seems to work fine in all browsers from my desktop but when I try to load the page using my iPad or iPhone it just shows the play icon with a line through it indicating it can't play it. I tried changing the source for the mp4 video to a direct link to the mp4 video and straight away the iPad started playing it.

Is there something special I need to do that I've missed in ordered to make my method compatible for iDevices? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To make your videos playable on iOS devices, you need to implement support for *byte-range* (or *partial*) requests. These type of requests allow to download not the whole content, but partially, chunk by chunk (typical *streaming*). And this is the only way how iOS devices get and play videos on the page.

Partial requests use `Range` header to tell the server next chunk position and size. Server on the other side responses with `206 Partial Content` and requested chunk contents.

You can find several implementations for ASP.NET handlers which can handle partial requests in internet. I suggest to use **[StaticFileHandler](http://code.google.com/p/talifun-web/wiki/StaticFileHandler)** for this: easy to install and also has caching capabilities out of box. It also can be delivered via Nuget, but the package is called [Talifun.Web](http://nuget.org/packages/Talifun.Web).

To configure StaticFileHandler, register the handler in web.config for *mp4* files and configure it in separate configuration section:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="StaticFileHandler" type="Talifun.Web.StaticFile.Config.StaticFileHandlerSection, Talifun.Web" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
  </configSections>

  <StaticFileHandler webServerType="NotSet">
    <!-- The defaults to use when an extension is found that does not have a specific rule  -->
    <fileExtensionDefault name="Default" serveFromMemory="true" maxMemorySize="100000" compress="true"/>
    <!-- Specific rules for extension types -->
    <fileExtensions>
        <fileExtension name="VideoStaticContent" extension="3gp, 3g2, asf, avi, dv, flv, mov, mp4, mpg, mpeg, wmv" serveFromMemory="true" maxMemorySize="100000" compress="false"/>
    </fileExtensions>
  </StaticFileHandler>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="StaticContentHandler" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.mp4" type="Talifun.Web.StaticFile.StaticFileHandler, Talifun.Web"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If can also easily apply your custom logic, for example authorization or custom video file source, by creating your ASP.NET handler and calling `StaticFileManager` directly.

```
public class MyOwnVideoHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Authorization or any other stuff.
        ...

        // Get file from your storage.
        FileInfo file = ...;

        // Serve the file with StaticFileHandler.
        StaticFileManager.Instance.ProcessRequest(new HttpContextWrapper(context), file);
    }
}
```

Also, you can take a look at [Scott Mitchell's article about partial requests](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx) for details and use the handler written by its author: it worked for me, but it doesn't have caching capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

@whyleee is correct. I can't speak on how good StaticFileHandler is, but I had been facing this same issue myself and it was driving me crazy. A `Range` header must be included in the `Request` and `Response` headers for this to work properly. For example, a slight modification to your code, with some code from my own Handler, looks like this (keep in mind that this is using an .ashx handler):

```
//First, accept Range headers.
context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")

//Then, read all of the bytes from the file you are requesting.
Dim file_info As New System.IO.FileInfo(clipLocation)
Dim bytearr As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(file_info.FullName)

//Then, you will need to check for a range header, and then serve up a 206 Partial Content status code in your response.
Dim startbyte As Integer = 0
If Not context.Request.Headers("Range") Is Nothing Then
    //Get the actual byte range from the range header string, and set the starting byte.
    Dim range As String() = context.Request.Headers("Range").Split(New Char() {"="c, "-"c})
    startbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range(1))

    //Set the status code of the response to 206 (Partial Content) and add a content range header.
    context.Response.StatusCode = 206
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", String.Format(" bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startbyte, bytearr.Length - 1, bytearr.Length))
End If

//Finally, write the video file to the output stream, starting from the specified byte position.
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytearr, startbyte, bytearr.Length - startbyte)
```

As I said though, this is code for an .ashx handler so I'm not sure how much it applies to your situation, but I hope it helps you out!