# Streaming video file to idevice

Tags: asp.net, ios, streaming

I'm newbie of asp.net
I try to streaming mp4 file using ashx, it works with some browsers on desktop, but idevices can play it.
I have searched around, many solutions said about range header, I try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125275/net-mvc-streaming-mp4-to-idevice-issue) of Mr. [Martin-Brennan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875941/martin-brennan), but it still doesn't work with me :(, here is my code. Sorry for my English, thanks!

By the way, I want to ask about rewrite url of video , my video url is `http://mydomain/video/test.mp4` is there possible to rewrite to `http://mydomain/a23sdsf21ds/test.mp4`, I can't rewrite url with extension

```
//First, accept Range headers.
context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
//Then, read all of the bytes from the file you are requesting.
var file_info = new System.IO.FileInfo(context.Server.MapPath("~/media/test.mp4"));
var bytearr = File.ReadAllBytes(file_info.FullName);

//Then, you will need to check for a range header, and then serve up a 206 Partial Content status code in your response.
var startbyte = 0;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["Range"]))
{
            var cs = new Char[] { '=', '-' };
            //Get the actual byte range from the range header string, and set the starting byte.
            var range = context.Request.Headers["Range"].Split(cs);
            startbyte = (int)Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);

            //Set the status code of the response to 206 (Partial Content) and add a content range header.
            context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", String.Format(" bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startbyte, bytearr.Length - 1, bytearr.Length));
        }
  //Finally, write the video file to the output stream, starting from the specified byte position.
  context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytearr, startbyte, bytearr.Length - startbyte);
```